# Bootstrap Carousel Caption Top Alignment?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, carousel

I'm not trying to do anything too fancy here, but instead of the Bootstrap Carousel Captions defaulting to aligning to the bottom of the Carousel, how do I get them to default align to the top?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add this to your css to change the element position:

```
.carousel-caption {
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
}
```

See **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57wxT/)**

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 5):

You could also:

```
.carousel-caption {
   position: absolute;
   top:-40px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 supports the following class: `text-left`, which aligns the content text to the left. So:

```
<div class="carousel-caption text-left">
```